# momentjs and react - to disable days checked against an array of days

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

```
<Query query={GET_SPACE} 
  variables={{ 
    spaceId: this.props.spaceId,
    fromDate: today,
    toDate: moment().add(3, 'years').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
  }}
>
  {({ loading, error, data }) => {
    if (loading) return null;
    if (error) return null;

    const { space } = data;
    const days = space.calendar.days;

    return (
      <div className={css.datePickerContainer}>
        <DayRangePicker
          month={month}
          selectDate={selectDate}
          startDate={startDate}
          endDate={endDate}
          onInteraction={this.handleDayPickerChange}
          onMonthChange={this.handleMonthChange}
          isDisabled={(d) => d.isBefore(today, 'day')}
          classNames={{header: 'fs-ignore-rage-clicks'}}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }}
</Query>
```

In this query, I have a constant `days` that gives me an array of `bookable` days and each day has `date`, `bookable` which can be `true` or `false`, and `open` which can also be `true` or `false` like below:

```
{
  "date": "2019-07-01",
  "bookable": true,
  "open": true
}
```

What I want to achieve now is something like below.. to disable days that has `bookable : false`.

`isDisabled={(d) => d.isBefore(today, 'day') && disable days that has bookable: false}`
where `d` is a `moment`.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, something like this would work:

`isDisabled={(d) => d.isBefore(today, 'day') && 
days.find(day => day.date === d.format('YYYY-MM-DD') && !day.bookable)`

A bit of explanation:

`days.find` will return the first element of the array which returns `true` with the function provided. This element is `truthy`, therefore the condition is correct. If not found, `days.find` will return `undefined`, cancelling the condition.

Comment: I tried doing this `(d) => d.isBefore(today, 'day') && 
days.find(day => day.date === d.format('YYYY-MM-DD') && !day.bookable)` but now none of my days are disabled

Comment: Check if `day.date` and `d.format('YYYY-MM-DD')` are absolutely the same format.

Comment: If they are, check if your results are all `bookable: true`

Comment: Yes this is called a `moment`. Which is why we have to call `d.format('YYYY-MM-DD')`

Answer (score 0):

You could include an array with unbookable dates and check if the current date is inside it:

```
{({ loading, error, data }) => {
if (loading) return null;
if (error) return null;

const { space } = data;
const days = space.calendar.days;
//filter the nonbookable objects than return only date
const notBookable = days.filter((el) => !el.bookable).map((elem) => return elem.date);
return (
  <div className={css.datePickerContainer}>
    <DayRangePicker
      month={month}
      selectDate={selectDate}
      startDate={startDate}
      endDate={endDate}
      onInteraction={this.handleDayPickerChange}
      onMonthChange={this.handleMonthChange}
      isDisabled={(d) => d.isBefore(today, 'day') && notBookable.includes(d)}
      classNames={{header: 'fs-ignore-rage-clicks'}}
    />
  </div>
);
}}
```

and same as the other poster: would work as long as d is the same format as date.

to make it complete and if d is a different format use `notBookable.includes(d.format('YYYY-MM-DD'))`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but he did say that `d` is a `moment`, In such, `notBookable.includes(d)` wouldn't work.

Comment: therefore i added the comment that this works as long as d is the same format as date in the object